# Create sqlite database once on startup

Tags: react-native, sqlite, create-table

I'm working on a hackathon for my local college and its my first time working with react native, I have some measurable skills in react and I want to learn new things, now I want to create a database table when a `"landing page"` is opened, it works, just not the way I want to. I want to create the tables once and if they exist I don't want anything to happen, but they get overwritten and then records are cleared each time, which creates frustration in order to create an account over and over again. I want to start integrating the database with my frontend and finish on the application but I'm stuck on this issue. Any ideas

```
import React, {Component, useEffect} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { Image, View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions, StatusBar, Layout, TouchableOpacity  } from 'react-native';
import Logo from '../components/assets/logo.png'    
import Login from './Login';
import { openDatabase } from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';    
import SignUp from './SignUp';
import Dash from './Dashboard';
import Reminder from './Reminder';

var db = openDatabase({ name: 'UserDatabase.db' });

function LoginPage(){

}

function Welcome({navigation}){    
    useEffect(() => {
        db.transaction(function (txn) {
          txn.executeSql(
            "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='user' AND name='data'",
            [],
            function (tx, res) {
              console.log('item:', res.rows.length);
              if (res.rows.length == 0) {                  
                  txn.executeSql(
                    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(user_id VARCHAR(75) PRIMARY KEY, Full_Name VARCHAR(75), Email VARHCAR(75), user_Password VARHCAR(75))',
                    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, content VARCHAR(75), date VARCHAR(75), Type VARCHAR(75), Completed VARCHAR(5))',
                    []
                  );
                  alert('Created database');
                  }else {
                    alert('database failed');
                  }                
              }            
          );
        });
      }, []);
    return (
        <View style={style.root}>
            <Image source={Logo} style={style.icon} /> 
            <Text style={style.title}>Note-ify</Text>  

            <View style={style.container}>
                <Text style={style.caption}>Welcome</Text>
                <Text style={style.message}>
                    Welcome To Note-ify. The all in one platform to manage your time effectively. 
                    To begin your journey please start by logging in or signing up. ITS FREE!
                </Text>

                <View style={style.parent}>
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                        title="Login"
                        style={style.login}
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}>

                        <Text style={style.login_caption}>Login</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity 
                        title="Sign Up"
                        style={style.signup}
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Register')}>
                    
                        <Text style={style.signup_content}>Sign Up</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            
            </View>  
        </View>                     

    );
}


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App(){
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
                <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={SignUp} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
                <Stack.Screen name="Dash" component={Dash} options={{headerShown: false}} />  
                <Stack.Screen name="Reminder" component={Reminder} options={{headerShown: false}}/>          
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

export default App;

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    root:{
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    },
    icon:{          
        alignSelf: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',               
        width: 100,        
        height: 100,
        marginTop: 85,
        position:'absolute',        
        zIndex:1,
    },
    title:{
        marginTop: 200,
        fontSize: 26,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',      
    },
    container:{
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: '#ffb900',
        width: '100%',
        height: 350,
        borderTopRightRadius: 45,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 45,
        bottom: 0,        
    },
    parent:{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    caption:{
        fontSize: 28,
        paddingLeft: 25,
        paddingTop: 15,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    message:{
        fontSize: 18,
        paddingLeft: 20,
        paddingTop: 20,
    },
    login:{
        width: 120,
        height: 45,
        backgroundColor: '#111',  
        marginLeft: 25,      
        marginTop: 25,
        borderRadius: 25
    },
    login_caption:{
        color: '#fff',
        textAlign: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingTop: 12,        
    },
    signup:{
        width: 120,
        height: 45,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',          
        marginLeft: 25,  
        marginTop: 25,           
        borderRadius: 25
    },
    signup_content:{
        color:'#111',
        textAlign: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingTop: 12,   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your actual code then there is no way to overwrite the tables because you are using `IF NOT EXISTS` in the `CREATE TABLE` statements.

A problematic part in your code is this query:

```
SELECT name 
FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE type='table' AND name='user' AND name='data'
```

Obviously you are trying to find out if the 2 tables already exist by executing the above query, but your logic is wrong.
This query never returns a row, because there is no way that the column `name` would be equal to `'user'` **AND** `'data'` in the same row.

You could get results if you used the operator `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
SELECT name 
FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE type='table' AND (name='user' OR name='data')
```

but, this would return 0 or 1 or 2 rows depending on the existence of either of the tables.

In any case, remove this query because it is not needed at all.

All you need is the 2 `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...` statements and nothing more.

Also, check if by any chance, there is code that deletes the database, so when you restart the app, the database is recreated.

Comment: I've done your suggested method, but my login isn't working, can provide my code for some suggestions

Comment: @PureWare-LegendsOfGaming my answer is not about your login but about the creation (or not if they exist) of the tables.

Comment: I am aware, but I believe they are connected, registration works fine, but login doesn't, but it's fine I'll ask somewhere else